# how to insert ul tag data to mysql database

Tags: php, insert, tags, html-lists

```
<ul id="myUL" name="ListItem[]">
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test1</li>
</ul>
```

This is my html coding and i need to put these data into the database.i send these array to my controller but it's empty.

Comment: Please show us your code so we can help

Comment: Please ask proper Questions. See the wiki for more information. Remember we don't write your code.

Comment: See HTML form inputs for submitting to backend databases. Standard HTML tags won't be submitted.

Comment: @JustBaron But with JS you could get outerHTML information. So if you get the element over the it the list will be included. But the explenation isn't worth it for this question.

Comment: @OliverBähler Agreed.

Comment: <ul id="myUL" name="ListItem[]">
                                    <li>test1</li>
                                    <li>test1</li>
                                    <li>test1</li>
                                    <li>test1</li>

                                </ul>

Comment: Look into HTML `select`

Comment: sorry,i can't understood.i'm try to create to-do list and i need to insert this data into database

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get the string-Output of your wanted elements.

```
<div id="liste">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
 </div>

 <script>
 var ele = document.getElementById('liste');
 alert(ele.innerHTML);
 </script>
```